# Why MLE estimate each parameter sperately?

Tags: probability, statistics

MLE told us, if a distribution $D(x;\theta_1, \theta_2)$ has likelihood function $L$, then we have

$$
\hat{\theta}_1 = \mathrm{argmax}_{\theta_1} \, L(x;\theta_1,\theta_2) \\
\hat{\theta}_2 = \mathrm{argmax}_{\theta_2} \, L(x;\theta_1,\theta_2)
$$

But why these parameters can be estimated seprately, instead of
$$
\hat{\theta'}_1, \hat{\theta'}_2 = \mathrm{argmax}_{\theta_1,\,\theta_2} \, L(x; \theta_1, \theta_2)
$$

I believe in most cases, $L(\hat{\theta'}_1, \hat{\theta'}_2) >L(\hat{\theta}_1, \hat{\theta}_2)$, because $(\hat{\theta'}_1, \hat{\theta'}_2)$ is the point where $L$ gets the maximum.

Comment: Are you sure you have everything right? The quantity $\hat{\theta}_1 = \mathrm{argmax}_{\theta_1} \, L(x;\theta_1,\theta_2)$ doesn't make sense to me as stated, since $L(x;\theta_1,\theta_2) = p_{\theta_1, \theta_2}(x)$ depends on both $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$; you can't optimize it just over $\theta_1$ without knowing what $\theta_2$ is. You could assume some prior over $\theta_2$ and then optimize the resulting $p_{\theta_1}(x)$, but then you are asking a very different question from your second one.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, my textbook said it will be a system of equations: $\{ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_i} = 0 \}$, and [Wikipedia's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Continuous_distribution,_continuous_parameter_space) also uses first order derivative to calculate each parameter instead of using total derivative.

Comment: Setting all the partial derivatives to $0$ is also what you do if you want to minimize over multiple variables simultaneously, though.